# Get a file out of MongoDB GridFS with no filename with mongofiles

Tags: mongodb, filenames, gridfs

There are files in GridFS:

```
In [1]: import pymongo

In [2]: c = pymongo.Connection('localhost', 49996)

In [3]: gfsf = c.wss_test.fs.files.find()

In [4]: gfsf.next()
Out[4]: 
{u'_id': ObjectId('51ad37067662579917000000'),
 u'chsum': u'18848aca1fc0980524d84aed3cc87dce',
 u'chunkSize': 1048576L,
 u'compressed': 0L,
 u'creationDate': u'2013-06-04T00:38:30',
 u'json': 1L,
 u'length': 15L,
 u'md5': u'18848aca1fc0980524d84aed3cc87dce',
 u'uploadDate': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 0, 38, 30)}
```

But mongofiles only spits out the length - there's no filename:

```
$ mongofiles -h localhost:49996 -d wss_test list
connected to: localhost:49996
    15
    62
    14
```

Since all `mongofiles` ops are by filename, what now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, mongofiles only works with filename, which is completely optional in the GridFS spec. If you need to work with your files through mongofiles make sure you add filenames to the files.